# How to multiply a single column in a data.frame by a number

Tags: r

I would like to know how to muliply a single column by 5 from a txt file that I used a script to read. I only know how to mulitply all of the columns by a number, but not a single column. 
This is my script for reading the txt file:

```
d = read.table(file="tst1.txt",header=TRUE)
```

Answer (score 21):

Lets suppose your dataframe `d` has a column named "number" (you can see the actual names of the columns in the dataframe using `str(d)`). To multiply the column "number" by 5, use:

```
# You are referring to the column "number" within the dataframe "d"
d$number * 5

# The last command only shoes the multiplication.

# If you want to replace the original values, use
d$number <- d$number * 5

# If you want to save the new values in a new column, use
d$numberX5 <- d$number * 5
```

Also, try referring to the standard R documentation, which you can find in the [official page](http://www.r-project.org/).

Answer (score 5):

`d[,i]<-d[,i]*5`. See `?Extract` for more information about extracting parts of objects.